# Unexpected equality tests, Equals(a, a) evaluates to false

Tags: c#

Given the struct S1:

```
unsafe readonly struct S1
{
    public readonly int A1, A2;
    public readonly int* B;

    public S1(int a1, int a2, int* b)
    {
        A1 = a1;
        A2 = a2;
        B = b;
    }
}
```

and an equality test:

```
int x = 10;
var a = new S1(1, 2, &x);
var b = new S1(1, 2, &x);

var areEqual = Equals(a, b);  // true
```

`areEqual` evaluates to true, as expected.

Now lets slightly change our struct to S2 (replacing the pointer with a string):

```
unsafe readonly struct S2
{
    public readonly int A1, A2;
    public readonly string C;

    public S2(int a1, int a2, string c)
    {
        A1 = a1;
        A2 = a2;
        C = c;
    }
}
```

with an analog test:

```
var a = new S2(1, 2, "ha");
var b = new S2(1, 2, "ha");

var areEqual = Equals(a, b);  // true
```

this evaluates to true as well.

Now the interesting part. If we combine both structs to S3:

```
unsafe readonly struct S3
{
    public readonly int A1, A2;
    public readonly int* B;
    public readonly string C;

    public S3(int a1, int a2, int* b, string c)
    {
        A1 = a1;
        A2 = a2;
        B = b;
        C = c;
    }
}
```

and test for equality:

```
int x = 10;
var a = new S3(1, 2, &x, "ha");
var b = new S3(1, 2, &x, "ha");

var areEqual = Equals(a, b);  // false
```

The equality test fails, unexpectedly. Even worse,

```
Equals(a, a); // false
```

does also fail the test.

Why do the last two equality tests evaluate to false?

### Edit

[Bugreport](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/42457) for reference. Fixed in .net 6.0.

Comment: I don't know how you get these results but in the first case `var areEqual = Equals(a, b);  // true` evaluates to 'false' (and not true) which is correct since the references are different.

Comment: @EfthymiosKalyviotis structs are value types and therefore compared by their value, not by their reference.

Comment: You are right on that. Just for your information in case it helps, I tried the same code in a console .net Core 3 and in .Net framework 4.7.2 apps and they produce different results.

Comment: In any case, in unsafe mode I would do my own comparer method.

Comment: @EfthymiosKalyviotis I've just tried it with netcore3.0 and net5.0 and got the same result.

Comment: sorry, my answer was neither entirely correct nor complete. I removed it until I get it right

Comment: can you show your equal method?

Comment: @MikeJ *my* Equals method is `Object.Equals`

Comment: Why don't you override the Equals method to have peace of mind?

Comment: I tried it and the comparison between S1 structs and it returns false (netcore 3.0)

Comment: @MatteoUmili good catch. I've slightly modified this version from the original one. That changed the packing of the struct and causes this case to fail. If you add another int after `A` it works as stated: `public readonly int A, D;`

Comment: I think that you should edit the question because the S1 comparison may lead users on the wrong way

Comment: @MatteoUmili That's a demonstrating that object.Equals is able to compare object references properly, at least in certain situations.  It's a relevant part of the question.  The fact that it's not any one field that's the problem, but the combination of them, that makes the question what it is.

Comment: I was talking about the part where you state the comparison between S1 returns true

Comment: @MatteoUmili yeah I was already working on fixing it. Although, for 32 bit targets this should have worked, because the pointer size there is only 4 byte.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual comparison of the instances is performed by [ValueType.Equals](https://source.dot.net#System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/ValueType.cs,d8b9b308e644b983,references). Here is the implementation:

```
public override bool Equals(object? obj)
{
    if (null == obj)
    {
        return false;
    }
    Type thisType = this.GetType();
    Type thatType = obj.GetType();

    if (thatType != thisType)
    {
        return false;
    }

    object thisObj = (object)this;
    object? thisResult, thatResult;

    // if there are no GC references in this object we can avoid reflection
    // and do a fast memcmp
    if (CanCompareBits(this))
        return FastEqualsCheck(thisObj, obj);

    FieldInfo[] thisFields = thisType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    for (int i = 0; i < thisFields.Length; i++)
    {
        thisResult = thisFields[i].GetValue(thisObj);
        thatResult = thisFields[i].GetValue(obj);

        if (thisResult == null)
        {
            if (thatResult != null)
                return false;
        }
        else
        if (!thisResult.Equals(thatResult))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

We can see that basically it performs a bit level comparison if there are no GC references (classes referenced in your fields), otherwise it will invoke Equals on every field of your struct.

When you have a field of pointer type (int* in your case) and you use Reflection to get its value, then the value you get is boxed as a [System.Reflection.Pointer](https://source.dot.net#System.Private.CoreLib/Pointer.cs,db61fdb4cc1d06a1).

We can see that it is a class, so no bit-level comparison will be performed.

So it will invoke Pointer.Equals, but unfortunately we can see by the Pointer class source code that it isn't overridden, so the check performed will be if the references of the object are the same:

```
public sealed unsafe class Pointer : ISerializable
{
    // CoreCLR: Do not add or remove fields without updating the ReflectionPointer class in runtimehandles.h
    private readonly void* _ptr;
    private readonly Type _ptrType;

    private Pointer(void* ptr, Type ptrType)
    {
        Debug.Assert(ptrType.IsRuntimeImplemented()); // CoreCLR: For CoreRT's sake, _ptrType has to be declared as "Type", but in fact, it is always a RuntimeType. Code on CoreCLR expects this.
        _ptr = ptr;
        _ptrType = ptrType;
    }

    public static object Box(void* ptr, Type type)
    {
        if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));
        if (!type.IsPointer)
            throw new ArgumentException(SR.Arg_MustBePointer, nameof(ptr));
        if (!type.IsRuntimeImplemented())
            throw new ArgumentException(SR.Arg_MustBeType, nameof(ptr));

        return new Pointer(ptr, type);
    }

    public static void* Unbox(object ptr)
    {
        if (!(ptr is Pointer))
            throw new ArgumentException(SR.Arg_MustBePointer, nameof(ptr));
        return ((Pointer)ptr)._ptr;
    }

    void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        throw new PlatformNotSupportedException();
    }

    internal Type GetPointerType() => _ptrType;
    internal IntPtr GetPointerValue() => (IntPtr)_ptr;
}
```

So the comparison will return false because you have a pointer.

Comment: Considering that a pointer should conceptually be a value-type bearing just a void*, but ok, let's make it managed void*+Type, either way, not providing an Equals override that would compare the value (=the address! not teh data behind the address) sounds like a bug to me. But I doubt it's a new piece of code. Unsafe code blocks and pointers were there, like, forever. They wouldn't just remove .Equals with a patch later. That piece probably is quite old and not changed often. So the Pointer lacking this may actually have some reason behind. I really wonder, what was that!

Comment: While these are some very interesting findings, can you point to a source that actually confirms that `int*` is `System.Reflection.Pointer`? Because I don't believe so. 1. `typeof(int*)` is `System.Int32*`. 2. `sizeof(int*)` is 8 which definitely is not possible `System.Reflection.Pointer`, because it has 2 members: one pointer and one handle. 3. `System.Reflection.Pointer` itself has a member of type `void*`, that doesn't really make sense to me. 4. `System.Reflection.Pointer` is not marshalable. I assume that pointers are primitive types just like `int`, `float`, ...

Comment: @Timo You can test it yourself. If you use reflection to get the pointer Value you will see the the type of the object returned when you run `GetValue` is `System.Pointer`.
Just copy and run the code from: FieldInfo[] thisFields..... till the end of the method. I think that somewhere the pointer is boxed because the framework needs an object for its reasonings

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Very surprising nonetheless. The boxing nature also explains why the identity comparison `Equals(a, a)` fails. During boxing the value is copied into an object and so the Equals method gets two independent copies of `a`. This also means that the boxing of the `int*` into a `System.Reflection.Pointer` will create to different handles and reference equality fails.

Comment: And `S1` works despite having a pointer, because apparently `CanCompareBits` is fine with it in that case and suddenly the behavior of the type is dependent on the layout of its host class. Question is: should pointer equality really be dependent on the layout of its host object?

Comment: @MatteoUmili I think you should clarify the _"the underlying type will be System.Pointer"_ part. This is the type when the value is boxed, not the underlying type. Also, the type is `System.Reflection.Pointer`.

Comment: @Timo I edited the answer. Also, to answer to your latest doubt ("should pointer equality really be dependent on the layout of its host object?"): probably not, we are in some corner case like the [one that was there when using floats in structs that caused comparison troubles](http://www.mazong1123.com/fixed-net-framework-10-years-old-bug/)